# Erro em tempo de execução. Falha na operação tentada VBA Outlook

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, visual-basic-6, macro, outlook

Criei uma macro para executar uma rotina no outlook. O código funciona perfeitamente em um PC, mas quando vou replicar o código para outra macro recebo a seguinte mensagem:

Erro em tempo de execução '-2147221233(8004010f)
Falha na operação tentada. Objeto não encontrado

O erro parece no seguinte trecho:

```
Set ol = New Outlook.Application
Set ns = ol.GetNamespace("MAPI")

'Erro aqui:
Set fol_CGR = ns.Folders(1).Folders("CGR")
Set fol_UDI = ns.Folders(1).Folders("UDI")
```

Ja li diversos foruns e não encontrei nada semelhante. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

O problema foi resolvido explicitando o endereço do folder default

```
Set fol_CGR = ns.Folders(1).Folders("Pasta")
```

Substituido por

```
Set fol_CGR = ns.Folders("emailaqui@email.com").Folders("CGR")
```